# GROUP BY over data in PowerPivot

Tags: sql, powerpivot, dax

In my PowerPivot I have a master data table which comes via an extract from system x. Now I want to be able to "GROUP BY" over a certain column from the same data. What would be the best approach here? There are more than 600.000 lines involved.

I have already tried following DAX query but it won't work:

```
SUMMARIZE('SAP extract', [cost element], sum('SAP extract'[val]))
```

Returns:

> Query(1,, 47) Function SUMMARIZE expects a column name as argument number 3.

Answer (score 1):

Kris,

I would suggest creating a new measure -- guessing from you question, that would probably be a simple **SUM** (see [documentation here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sum-function-dax-HA102839042.aspx)), something like:

```
=SUM(Sales[Amt])
```

This should be then automatically added to your currently active powerpivot table.

If you then want to group the data by anything, **simply drag the dimension** into the *rows* section and you should be able to see the aggregated sums sliced by the dimension you chose.

Hope this helps.